# Error in surface revolution in Schaum's Calculus

Tags: integration, surfaces

Flipping through Schaum Calculus I stumbled in a problem (the third of chapter 36) that is wrong:

[image]

The solution is obscure and this error doesn't look a typo. I'm trying to understand what happened here. Steps are strange and anyway surely something went wrong because the correct solution is $\frac{\pi \left( 28 - 9 \ln(3) - \ln^2(3) \right)}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is wrong. When a curve is rotated about the y-axis, the area of the resulting surface of revolution is given by $S = \int^{d}_{c} 2 \pi x \sqrt{1 + (\frac{dx}{dy})^2} dy$.

Comment: After all not so obscure. He started from a wrong formula but then he simply brought it to its final consequences.